# editing a certain column in an annotation file

Tags: awk, annotations

I'm trying to edit an annotation file. The table looks like this:

```
chr10   HAVANA  gene    92834713        93059493        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000138190.16"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    92878092        92878289        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000225118.1"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    93059663        93060426        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000226425.1"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    93060808        93069536        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000187553.8"
```

I want to remove the gene 'version' in the gene_id column, and to get something like this `"ENSG00000187553"` instead of `"ENSG00000187553.8"`

```
chr10   HAVANA  gene    92834713        93059493        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000138190"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    92878092        92878289        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000225118"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    93059663        93060426        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000226425"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    93060808        93069536        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000187553"
```

any ideas how can I do that? (using awk or some other similar command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a substitution to remove the version from the last field:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[.][0-9]+"/, "\"", $NF)}1' file
chr10 HAVANA gene 92834713 93059493 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000138190"
chr10 HAVANA gene 92878092 92878289 . - . gene_id "ENSG00000225118"
chr10 HAVANA gene 93059663 93060426 . - . gene_id "ENSG00000226425"
chr10 HAVANA gene 93060808 93069536 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000187553"
```

Since the field in question is the last one, as pointed out in the comments a nicer option could be to treat the line as a whole and in that way preserve the original spacing:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[.][0-9]+"/, "\"")}1' file
chr10   HAVANA  gene    92834713        93059493        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000138190"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    92878092        92878289        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000225118"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    93059663        93060426        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000226425"
chr10   HAVANA  gene    93060808        93069536        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000187553"
```

Comment: with `sub(/\.[0-9]+"$/, "\"")` you can preserve the original spacing.

Comment: Thanks, @karakfa, I like that much better.  Updated!